# how does url within function body get compiled

Tags: c++, function, compiler-construction, compiler-warnings, goto

I just pasted a url to my code, and forgot to comment it, but I was surprised to see MSVC++ compiled it successfully. My code is like this,

```
void my_function()
{
    http://www.google.co.in/
}
```

How come this gets compiled by MSVC++?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually, `http` followed by a *colon* is treated as a **label** by C++, which you can use in `goto` statements (like `goto http;`), and the rest (i.e `//www.google.co.in`) is treated as single line comment. That's why it gets compiled.

See more,

```
 void your_function()
 {

        http://www.google.co.in/

        https://www.crazy_c++.com/

        ftp://c++_is_fun.edu

        //your code here
        int i = 10 ; //atleast one line of code is needed here to get compiled!
 }
```

---

By the way, I don't think the example you've written would get compiled. There should be at least one line of code after the url, only then it gets compiled on my PC. I'm using MSVC++ 2008.

Comment: Of course, two URLs using the same protocol would create a label name conflict.

Comment: @Martin: after the last url, it needs at least one line code. otherwise, it doesn't get compiled on MSVC++2008. I'm not sure if that is required by the C++ Standard. I need to look into it.

Comment: yes, some sort of statement has to follow the label, because the grammar only allows a label to appear right before a statement

Answer (score 1):

Unquoted `//` in C++ is a comment. So after stripping comments, your code will look like this:

```
void my_function()
{
    http:
}
```

So `http:` is just a label that can be used with `goto`.